# java program planet using enums

Tags: java, boolean

i have an enum called planets and it has 2 fields: how many moons are in a planet (int) and if the planet is Terrestrial or Jovian (boolean).  Then i have program called planet info which list each planet type by Iterate through each planet to determine type. But i cant seem to figure out how to check if it is a Terrestrial or Jovian.

Heres a sample output :

```
Terrestrial planets:
MERCURY
VENUS
EARTH
MARS

Jovian planets:
MERCURY
VENUS
EARTH
MARS
```

my code:
the enum:

```
public enum Planet {
    MERCURY (0,true), 
    VENUS (0,true),
    EARTH (1,true),
    MARS (2,true), 
    JUPITER (67,false),
    SATURN (62,false),
    URANUS (27,false),
    NEPTUNE(14,false);

    private int moon; 
    private boolean isTerrestrial;

    private Planet(int c,boolean f){
        moon = c;
        isTerrestrial = f; 
    }

    public int getMoon(){
        return moon;
    }   

    public boolean getIsTerrestrial(){
        return isTerrestrial; 
    }
}
```

the other class:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class PlanetInfo {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Planet mcy = Planet.MERCURY;
        Planet vns = Planet.VENUS;
        Planet rth = Planet.EARTH; 
        Planet mrs = Planet.MARS;
        Planet jpt = Planet.JUPITER;
        Planet strn = Planet.SATURN; 
        Planet urn = Planet.URANUS;
        Planet npt = Planet.NEPTUNE;

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Terrestrial planets:");
        for (Planet p : Planet.values()){
            if(p.equals(false)){
                System.out.println(p);
            } 
        }

        System.out.println("Enter a planet name:"); 
        String line = kb.nextLine().toUpperCase(); 

        switch(line){
            case "MERCURY":
            System.out.println(mcy + " has "+ mcy.getMoon()+" moons.");
            break; 
            case "VENUS" : 
            System.out.println(vns + " has "+ vns.getMoon()+" moons.");
            break; 
            case "EARTH":
            System.out.println(rth + " has "+ rth.getMoon()+" moons.");
            break; 
            case "MARS":
            System.out.println(mrs + " has "+ mrs.getMoon()+" moons.");
            break; 
            case"JUPITER":
            System.out.println(jpt + " has "+ jpt.getMoon()+" moons.");
            break; 
            case "SATURN":
            System.out.println(strn + " has "+ strn.getMoon()+" moons.");
            break; 
            case "URANUS":
            System.out.println(urn + " has "+ urn.getMoon()+" moons.");
            break;
            case "NEPTUNE":
            System.out.println(npt + " has "+ npt.getMoon()+" moons.");
            break; 
            default: 
            System.out.println("error, not a planet");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: You have to call your 'p.getIsTerrestrial()' method instead of 'p.equals(false)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting this instead of your for-each loop. It is working.

```
for (Planet p : Planet.values()){
            if(p.getIsTerrestrial()==(false)){
                System.out.println(p);
            }
        }
```

getIsTerrestrial is a boolean function and therefore equals() does not work on it.

Answer (score 2):

Add a static function to your `enum`, call it `getPlanetByName(String name)`.
The function should iterate through `Planet.values()` and return the one with the specified name.
Then, as soon as your user enters a planetName, you store it into

```
String userEnteredPlanetName
```

And then you simply call

```
Planet.getPlanetByName(userEnteredPlanetName).getIsTerrestrial();
```

This should also allow you to get rid of that huge switch-case block :)

Comment: Since that name is the enum value itself, there is such a method. it's called `Planet.valueOf(String name)`.

Comment: Hm, yes, you are right, though it would be nicer to also add a field "name" to the enum for more flexibility :)

Comment: It would be even nicer if the distiction between terrestrial and jovian was an enum instead of a boolean and if the Planet enum had a toString method for use in the output and if the params of the Planet constructor had speaking names...

Answer (score 2):

Simply use p.getIsTerrestrial() instead of p.equals(false).

```
 //print if its a Terrestrial Planet
 for (Planet p : Planet.values()){
        if(p.getIsTerrestrial()){
            System.out.println(p);
    } 
 }
```

I would also consider making planet a class containing a enum instead of having an enum with non static values (moon)

> An enum is a special "class" that represents a group of constants (unchangeable variables, like final variables).

Comment: thanks for the help much appreciated, i was doing ,equals and then i remembered its a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Use p.getIsTerrestrial() its alot better as some People already said.

```
 for (Planet p : Planet.values()){
    if(p.getIsTerrestrial())
    {
            //print if its a Terrestrial Planet
            System.out.println(p);
    }
    else {
     //print its a Joovian Planet (might wanna check for null values if null is possable to be passed on here)
    }
 }
```